# Run some code for jQuery widget only once during initialization for all instances on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

have some problem with running some initialization widget's code ONLY ONCE for all instances on the page.

Here is my situation...

I have to load JS file during the widget's initialization. Currently I do this inside `_create()` method.  But when I try to put 2 ore more instances on the page, widget tries to load same JS file several times. That's not good of course... so I need some mechanism for synchronization.

Any ideas how to better sync it?

I was thinking about some mechanism that would allow to run some code only ONCE for all widget's instances on the page of some intelligent JS loaded that wouldn't load same file twice and just controlled the process of loading and notified all interested parts when the process is finished.

**UPDATE**:

There are actually 2 problems with loading some JS file inside the widget:

1. Load files only once
2. Notify all widget's instances that JavaScript code ready to be used

JavaScript code from JS file may be used during the widget initialization, so I need notify widget that it loaded properly and ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i inderstood your need, so i hope this be helpful:

```
 var pluginName = "MyPlugin";
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {

        if(!$.data("body", "alreadyLoadedFile"))
        {
          //load your file
           $.data("body", "alreadyLoadedFile", true);
        }
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, 
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };
```

The main idea is to use the data on a dom element (like body tag), or give your js file an id  and check if it's exist on your page.